# Can I trigger dataimport from Spring Solr integration

Tags: spring-data-solr

I am trying to write a quick class to trigger the data import on solr. I know I can just use HttpClient, but I've already got Spring-Data-Solr configured and it has the server configured etc.

Is it possible to use the Query interface and the Solr Template to just send a request to dataimport request handler with "command=full-import" as params?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to `SolrTemplate` instance, you could execute a `SolrCallback` as follows:

```
solrTemplate.execute(new SolrCallback<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void doInSolr(SolrServer solrServer) throws SolrServerException, IOException {
        ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
        params.set("qt", "/dataimport");
        params.set("command", "full-import");
        solrServer.query(params);
        return null;
    }
});
```